# Can you force a function not to return to the previous stack and just SendRedirect in a Java Servlet?

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

I'm trying to write error handling for a hibernate related project, I'm still new so there should be a better solution than this, but the way I did it was by creating a separate layer for running the hibernate queries

Now when handling hibernate exceptions in that layer I need to somehow sendRedirect without going back to the rest of the code as sendRedirect would throw an exception (forward and include could work but I would rather sendRedirect)

I tried to prevent the rest of the code to know about how I handle exceptions in that layer, but now I wonder if this was a good approach

Code sample of what I tried but doesn't seem to work as expected

```
@WebServlet("/signup")
public class RegistrationController extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        if (email != null && password != null) {
            User user = new User(email, hashedPassword);
            UserRepo userRepo = UserRepo.getInstance();
            userRepo.create(user);
            response.sendRedirect(UrlMappingConstants.getInstance().getControllerUrl(PageNames.SIGN_IN_PAGE));
        }
    }
}
```

And when something goes wrong in userRepo.create I call this in the catch

```
public void handleError() {
    try {
        ThreadLocalContext.forward(ServiceNames.ERROR_REDIRECT);
    } catch (IOException | ServletException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And all that does is redirect to error page

```
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendRedirect(UrlMappingConstants.getInstance().getControllerUrl(PageNames.TEST_JSP));
    }
```